# Change the order of minimum in sums

Tags: real-analysis, summation

Is it possible to change the order of minimum as i did below:

$$\min_w \sum_x\sum_y f(x,y,w)^2 = \sum_x \min_w \sum_y f(x,y,w)^2
$$

If for all $x$ we have $$\min_w \sum_y f(x,y,w)^2,$$ then could I change the order of minimum?

Comment: sorry i missed the quadratic term so it is positiv. is there a formal proof ?

Comment: What do we have in the last paragraph?  You have an expression, but nothing it is compared to or equal to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not correct.  In the first you have to choose one value of $w$ to use in every term of the sum.  In the second you get to choose a different $w$ for every $x$. For example, take

$$\begin {array} {c|c|c|c} x&y&w&f(x,y,w)\\ \hline 0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&10\\0&1&0&0\\0&1&1&10\\1&0&0&10\\1&0&1&0\\1&1&0&10\\1&1&1&0
\end {array}$$
Here you want $x$ to agree with $w$.  The left side gives the same value regardless of $w$, which is $200$.  The right side gives $0$.